# Spamming EditText cause freezes

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a kind of quantity field with `+` and `-` buttons.

When the user clicks on those buttons it increments or decrements an integer inside an `EditText`. I use an `EditText` and not a `TextView` because the user can also edit the field manually with the keyboard.

When the user long-clicks, I start a thread which updates the `EditText` quickly, the thread is stopped when the user releases the button. The update is doing well but my app is getting laggy because of the `EditText` listeners.

I got a lot of log like that :

```
05-22 12:56:21.625: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(15137): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
05-22 12:56:21.635: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(15137): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
05-22 12:56:21.635: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(15137): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
05-22 12:56:21.635: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(15137): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
```

**I managed to avoid the freezes by setting to null the `KeyListener` before starting the thread**

```
editText.setKeyListener(null)
```

but I'm not very pleased with that solution because it changes the soft keyboard input type. Each time the user clicks on the buttons, the soft keyboard change from number input type to standard input type.

Is there another way to avoid freezes when spamming an `EditText` ?

Answer (score 1):

Well you can try something like this..

```
NumberKeyListener keyListener = new NumberKeyListener() {

        public int getInputType() {
        return InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER;
        }

        @Override
        protected char[] getAcceptedChars() {
        return new char[] { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '.', ':', '-', ',' };
        }
    };
```

and then set

```
editText.setKeyListener(keyListener);
```

This will make sure you get number input type..

hope this helps..

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already tried a solution like that but it has no effect.

Comment: Hey what do you know, I just added  `input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);` after `editText.setKeyListener(null);` and still that editText responded that implies you can you can use `input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);` on button release.

Comment: No it doesn't work because calling `setInputType` implies to call `setKeyListener`. See the docs http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setInputType(int)